# Jquery ScrollPane

Tags: jquery, jscrollpane

As anybody ever have add issue with still being able to scroll outside the boundaries of the div you are scrolling.

For legal reasons am unable to post the code sadly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It actually turned out to be the fact i was using jquery 1.2.6, I had to upgrade to jquery 1.3.2 to solved my issue.

Thank you for your comments Ace Trajkov

Answer (score 1):

If i assume correctly, you are using jScrollPane and the scroll container expands beyond the window dimensions on window resize. There is a bug in the code where the width and height is calculated for the content and container. Basically, you need to reassign the width and height on window resize. Here is a working example:

```
var oldWindowHeight = $(window).height();
var oldWindowWidth = $(window).width();
$(function () {
    $('.tdMiddleRightContent').each(function () {
        $(this).jScrollPane({
            showArrows: true,
            hideFocus: true
        });
        var api = $(this).data('jsp');
        var throttleTimeout;
        $(window).bind('resize', function () {
            var newWindowHeight = $(window).height();
            if ((newWindowHeight - oldWindowHeight) < 0) {
                $(".jspContainer").height($(".jspContainer").height() + (newWindowHeight - oldWindowHeight));
            }
            var newWindowWidth = $(window).width();
            if ((newWindowWidth - oldWindowWidth) < 0) {
                $(".jspContainer").width($(".jspContainer").width() + (newWindowWidth - oldWindowWidth));
            }
            if ($.browser.msie) {
                if (!throttleTimeout) {
                    throttleTimeout = setTimeout(function () {
                        api.reinitialise();
                        throttleTimeout = null;
                    }, 50);
                }
            } else {
                api.reinitialise();
            }
            oldWindowHeight = $(window).height();
            oldWindowWidth = $(window).width();
        });
    });
});
```